# Does GEE (Generalized Estimating Equations) need normality of residuals for inference in case of "approx. Gaussian" response?

Tags: regression, least-squares, residuals, generalized-estimating-equations, generalized-least-squares

A quick question. My intention is to analyze some numerical data across several categories (treat this as ANOVA, if you wish, but I'm going to focus on simple effects) that are "just numeric", but not specifically counts, not binary categories, not necessarily "always-skewed left or right". Let's say it's about data that can be meaningfully summarized with arithmetic means, but often (I saw it in many experiments) the empirical distributions, so also the residuals, were not quite normal. What I mean:

- some not big but visible outliers in residuals, deviating from the line in QQ against normality
- sometimes some mild skewness to left or right, but neither could be specifically expected; just observed pattern. No multiplicative relationships.
- sometimes mild "waves" occur in the distribution, but no 'local maxima', no local "clusters" are anticipated. Just random pattern

I could use the MMRM model for it, employing the Generalized Least Square (GLS) estimation. But this estimation, similarly to OLS, assumes Gaussian residuals and my statistical reviewers pays attention to this as hell!

I heard that the GEE estimation, although still the conditional distribution has to be specified (here Gaussian) doesn't have such formal assumption. It is an asymptotic method, using Wald's testing approach, so the more it's normal the better, but not formally forced.

Is this true? Are there any books that could confirm it that you know?